# Return Value of Drop down list

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu

**Edit.blade** when i click edit i want the drop-down-list to show the data which i have save from the database.

**Controller:**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    //
    $igcse = IGCSE_Student::findOrFail($id);
    $students = Student::all();
    $levels = Level::all();
    $classes = Classes::all();

    return view('igcse.edit', compact('igcse', 'students','levels','classes'));
}
```

**Edit.Blade**

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label>Status</label>
<select style="width: 200px" class="form-control" id="status" name="status" required>
<option value="0" >Please Select</option>
<option value="ACTIVE">ACTIVE</option>
<option value="WITHDRAW">WITHDRAW</option>
<option value="GRADUATE">GRADUATE</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**Note:**
In the drop-down-list i want to display the current status of the student from the database.

Comment: I'm confused... What data is the dropdown supposed to be showing when you have a prefilled select input already?

Comment: your options should be selected based on which value ?

Comment: i dnt know how to display in edit view the data which i have selected before in create view

Comment: So, ACTIVE WITHDRAW and GRADUATE are levels values ?

Comment: Can you add the sample data about what you have stored in database please.

Comment: they are called status. for example i have selected the student status into active. then suddenly i want to edit it and changed to withdraw i want the edit page show its current value

Comment: So, status is stored in student table ?

Comment: what you have tried so far ? stackoverflow is not a place someone write code on behalf of you.

Comment: In what table are the statuses held? this question is so limited its crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit structure should be like this

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Status</label>
<select style="width: 200px" class="form-control" id="status"   name="status" required>
    <option value="0" @if($igcse->status=='0') selected @endif>Please Select</option>
    <option value="ACTIVE" @if($igcse->status=='ACTIVE') selected @endif>ACTIVE</option>
    <option value="WITHDRAW" @if($igcse->status=='WITHDRAW') selected @endif>WITHDRAW</option>'
    <option value="GRADUATE" @if($igcse->status=='GRADUATE') selected @endif>GRADUATE</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: @Copain It's pleasure for me it helped you :D

Comment: @SagarGautam you should use ```{{$igcse->status=='value'?'selected':''}} ```  instead of ```@if($igcse->status=='0') selected @endif```
First @if should be used with blocks for inline use blade echo shortcut```{{}}``` and another point you forgot to use echo incase using ```@if ```
***P.S.*** I didn't downvoted this answer

Comment: @sumitsharma I've thought that way as well and is a good way but the answer i've added might be quiet easier to understand for who are new to laravel :D :D

Answer (score 0):

edit blade file should be like this

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Status</label>
<select style="width: 200px" class="form-control" id="status" name="status" required>
<option value="0" >Please Select</option>
<option value="ACTIVE" {{$igcse->status=='ACTIVE' ? 'selected' : '' }}>ACTIVE</option>
<option value="WITHDRAW" {{$igcse->status=='WITHDRAW' ? 'selected' : '' }}>WITHDRAW</option>
<option value="GRADUATE" {{$igcse->status=='GRADUATE' ? 'selected' : '' }}>GRADUATE</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are reffering to `students` and you want the `select` tag automatically select the `option` based from data on database.

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>Status</label>
  <select style="width: 200px" class="form-control" id="status" name="status" required>
   <option value="0" >Please Select</option>
   <option value="ACTIVE" @php($igcse->status == 'ACTIVE') ? echo 'selected' : "" @endphp>ACTIVE</option>
   <option value="WITHDRAW" @php($igcse->status == 'WITHDRAW') ? echo 'selected' : "" @endphp>WITHDRAW</option>
   <option value="GRADUATE" @php($igcse->status == 'GRADUATE') ? echo 'selected' : "" @endphp>GRADUATE</option>
 </select>
 </div>
```